# alterar data computada obtenida desde el store y pasarlo al componente modificado

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

una consulta,,
Necesito ayuda para alterar una variable computada que viene desde un getter en el store?

##### contexto:

Necesito modificar la variable que obtiene los estados (statuses) para cargarlos en un v-select, el cual se utliza en otras vistas tbn.
El tema es que en esta vista en particular, solo necesito los valores que **no** sean negativos (-). y pasarle statuses modificado al select de este componente.

En mi componente

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "ReasonsCreate",
  data() {
    return {
      loading: false,
      fetching: {
        status: false,
      },
      entity: {
        statu_id: null,
        name: "",
        is_only_mobile: false,
        order: 1,
      },
    };
  },
computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
     ... moreMethods...,

      statuses: "status/items",
    }),
  },
}
</script>

<template>
  <v-col cols="6">
    <v-select
       v-model="entity.statu_id"
       :label="$t('Status')"
       :items="statuses"
       :error-messages="errors.statu ? errors.statu : null"
       hide-details="auto"
       :loading="fetching.status"
       filled
       dense
    >
    </v-select>
 </v-col>
</template>
```

###### Vue Dev Tools

Esto es lo que viene en statuses si miramos desde vue Devtools (imagen1)
[image: vuedevtools-statuses]

Entonces mi pregunta va por ese lado,
para ver como altero "statuses" en este componente, para pasarlo al v-select, ya sin los valores en (-)

###### Valores esperados

[image: v-select expected values]

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1):

Sería solo filtrar tu arreglo de status con otra computada. Con una computada te traes todos tus valores como ya lo haces, y pues con otra computada solo filtras ese getter con valores > 0

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).